# How to process and print JSON array using expression language in jsp?

Tags: json, jsp

I am crating a json array of dynamic length in my BO class and passing that array to the controller.from controller I have send that array to the jsp successfully using expression language.now I am getting an exception on my for each loop end value.the end value is the length of the json array.
I am using `${array.length ()}` this.but getting number format exception.

Comment: It would help if we could look at an example JSON object that needs to be parsed, so we can provide a more detailed answer. Could you please edit your question to include this?

Comment: @ShotgunNinja [{"state":"WEST BENGAL","so/bo":"Ajodhya B.O","district":"Bankura","taluk":"Vishnupur"},{"state":"WEST BENGAL","so/bo":"Amral B.O","district":"Bankura","taluk":"Bishnupur"}]

This is my json array I'm passing to the jsp using ModelAndView.addObject("name",JSONObject)

maibnly I am Facing problem in Iterating the JsonArray using for each loop of jstl core.

If You have any solution please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got the Solution:

```
'<table>
<tr>
<% int lengthOfArray =(Integer)request.getAttribute("length");
%>
</tr>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="<%=lengthOfArray-1 %>">
    <tr>
  <td>
  <c:out value="${array.getJSONObject(i).getString('soBoOrZipcode')}"/>
  </td>
  <td>
  <c:out value="${array.getJSONObject(i).getString('taluk')}"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <c:out value="${array.getJSONObject(i).getString('district')}"/>
  </td> 
  <td>
    <c:out value="${array.getJSONObject(i).getString('state')}"/>
  </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach> 
</table>'
```